Translation help with motto
I have already tried Google translate and want to make sure it is accurate. I am looking for the translation for either “the Hunters of hunters” or “we hunt the hunters”
Thank you

The simplest answer is:
Venatores Venamur

You might also want to mention venatores venatorum to answer the hunters-of-hunters part of the question.
